# Accessing websphere 8 admin console remotely

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7, websphere-6.1, websphere-8

I am working on test env setup of WAS 8 on linux machine. can some one tell me how we will be able to access the admin console remotely after the installation? or rather what needs to be done so that we can access the admin console remotely?

Also it would be great if some one can provide some links about installing WAS 8 on linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed your WebSphere Server on a Internet Enabled server, you must be having the IP of the server. Using the IP address, you can access the WebSphere Admin console as :

```
     https://<Server IP Address>:9090/admin
```

or using host name as:

```
     https://<Server Host Name>:9090/admin
```

Please find the installation documentation here: --> [**WebSphere 8 Installation**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.installation.rsaws.doc/topics/t_install_was8.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess i am currently facing a firewall issue, i will check with the admin.